# Why Async Pipe works in a template, but Subscribe does not work in a component?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an NgRx Store with an app theme configuration. When I use `async` pipe in the `navbar.component.html`

```
<div class="navbar" [style.background]="(theme | async).uiElements['navbar_background'].getColor()">
```

and change the navbar background color from my `change-colors.component.ts`, everything works fine. But when I subscribe to theme changes inside the `navbar.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.theme = this.themeStore.select('theme');

    this.themeSub = this.theme.subscribe(
      () => console.log('subs works')
    );
  }
```

'subs works' text is not appearing in the console, i. e. subscription does not work. Why it can be so?

Theme reducer:

```
export function themeReducer(state = initialState, action: ThemeActions.ThemeActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case (ThemeActions.CHANGE_COLOR):    
      state.uiElements[action.payload.target] = new UiElement(
        state.uiElements[action.payload.target].name,
        action.payload.target,
        { R: action.payload.value.R, G: action.payload.value.G, B: action.payload.value.B }
      );

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: I fixed the problem by replacing `return state` with `return {...state}` in `themeReducer` function. However, it is still interesting why `async` pipe worked fine.

Comment: Did you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component? If had to create a new instance with `{...state}` it looks like Angular didn't detect changes. Anyway it's weird it didn't work in`ngOnInit`.

Comment: This could be due to what's in `initialState`. If you don't have deep enough initialization, the select mechanism doesn't watch for changes a the level you are mutating. (Not sure if it applies to ngrx, but have seen it with other redux).